# BorderContainer dojo with 2 ContentPane in top and 1 in bottom

Tags: javascript, dojo, border-container

I want a BorderContainer with this structure:

[image]

I've this code but it doesn't work. The height of the bottom doesn't work, so I don't know how to fix it.

```
                this.bc = new BorderContainer({
                    style: "height: 100%; width: 100%;",
                    design:'sidebar',
                    gutters:true,
                    liveSplitters:true,
                });

                this.cp1 = new ContentPane({
                    region: "leading",
                    style: "width: 50%;height : 50%;",
                    content: '<div style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>',
                    splitter:true
                });
                this.bc.addChild(this.cp1);

                this.cp2 = new ContentPane({
                    region: "center",
                    style: "width: 50%;height : 50%;",
                    content: '<div style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>',
                    splitter:true
                });
                this.bc.addChild(this.cp2);

                this.cp3 = new ContentPane({
                    region : "bottom",
                    style: "height : 50%",
                    content: '<div style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>',
                    splitter:true
                });
                this.bc.addChild(this.cp3);

                dijit.byId("containerPane").addChild(this.bc, 0);

                this.bc.startup();

                this.bc.resize();
```

Comment: can we have a quick jsfiddle if you can,

Comment: Have you tried adding this line?  this.bc.placeAt(document.body) (or wherever else you wish it to be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by the height of the bottom does not work, can you be more specific? Here is a working jsfiddle maybe this will help?
http://jsfiddle.net/edchat/1cr6hsfa/

The sizes are not working with 50% because the splitter and padding are taking up space, so you don't have room for both contentPanes to use 50%.

And I don't think you want to design:'sidebar'

```
design:'sidebar',
```